# Waiting for a command answer in laravel?

Tags: laravel, lumen

I am calling multi command in this command class:

```
public function handle()
{
    foreach ($this->argument('step') as $step) {
        if (command_exists("private:{$step}")) {
            $this->call("private:{$step}");

            $this->info("{$step} is completed");
            $this->line("-----");
        }
    }
}
```

I need to Waiting for each response in loop

Comment: I think you need to be a little bit more clear about what you want to do and what the problem is

Comment: This code already waiting for `$this->call("private:{$step}")` response - next step will not be started before this line return result.

Comment: `$this->call("private:{$step}")` dosent waiting response

Comment: @mohammad you could use [`$this->confirm("Are you sure you want to run private:{$step}?");`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#asking-for-confirmation), but I am not sure if it is available in Lumen.